# YouTube video is stucked for few seconds if I have enabled the layers.acceleration.force-enabled in Firefox

Tags: firefox, youtube, hardware-acceleration

If I have enabled `layers.acceleration.force-enabled`, the YouTube video usually get stucked for few seconds while the audio is playing fine, it never happend when I was in Manjaro, this problem is really annoying, please fix it!

```
CPU: Intel i5-4460
GPU: AMD RX580 8G 
RAM: 8GB DDR3 
Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1LTS
```

Comment: Do you have that issue with other browsers?

Comment: @Gravemind No, not in snap version of Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: @Gravemind There is also some audio issue on the Ubuntu Firefox in Google translator on the search page, and not happens to snap version of Firefox, either.

Comment: you have probably met Firefox issue,  not related to Ubuntu. Please report bug to Mozilla.

Comment: @Gravemind But it doesn't happen to the snap version of Firefox, only the Ubuntu Firefox.

Comment: please edit with output of snap version of Firefox and other one's  version. Maybe you have different versions, so in later one that bug is fixed.

Comment: @Gravemind It didn't happen to several previous versions of Snap Firefox, but it happens to the latest Ubuntu Firefox, I have had this issue since I switched to Ubuntu.

Comment: you just answered to your question. To be completely sure - try to install older Firefox version and check if issue exist. If no - it is a bug in Firefox.

Comment: Yes, it has happened to older Ubuntu Firefox since I switched to Ubuntu18.04.1 LTS, and it also didn't happen to every version of Snap Firefox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89387/discussion-between-gravemind-and-julianlai).

Comment: By the way, it happens to Twitch streaming, too.